# How to anonymize one more many readonly attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently on a case where I have model with readonly attributes and I'm trying to anonymize those attributes (meaning updating them with unrecognizable values) due to GDPR. It seems that Rails doesn't allow to do that (even by overriding the #readonly? and returning false in it) which makes sense because why updating an attribute that's not supposed to be updated right ? but have anyone had a similar case ? if so, did you go about it please ?

**Model**

```
class Medium < ApplicationRecord
  include Anonymous::ActiveRecord

  attr_readonly :access_id, :medium_reference_id

  def anonymize
    if self.class.readonly_attributes.include?("access_id") #useless because always true
      Medium.where(id: self.id).update_all(access_id: "#{self.id}_anonymized")
    end
    super
  end

  private
  
  def anonymization_definitions
    {
      access_id: "#{self.id}_anonymized",
      vehicle: "#{self.id}_anonymized",
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Is it a model constraint that prevents you from updating? Have you tried updating to what you want through the db, ie `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('sql statement...')`?

Comment: I put the model above. no validations or constraints in the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it on the db level. Using the `connection.execute`

```rb
random_id = SecureRandom.hex(9)
sql = <<~SQL
  UPDATE mediums
  SET access_id = #{random_id}
  WHERE id = #{self.id};
SQL

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

This will update the record in question, bypassing the readonly attribute. You could put this in an instance method on the Medium model

```rb
# app/models/medium.rb
def annonymize
  # Statement from above
end
```

And then could be invoked as

```rb
medium = Medium.find(<ID>)
medium.annonymize
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I'm actually using that gem (github.com/jamesstonehill/anonymous) which allows you to have anonymization definitions and which has a #anonymize method. But this method is calling #update_attributes which checks for #readonly? which I overrode but nothing changed. And from there, I got into the db level update with #update_all but yours might be better actually.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually used this line below. Probably not the best since I want to update one record but it doesn't check for readonly attributes and works for now.

```
Medium.where(id: self.id).update_all(access_id: "#{self.id}_anonymized")
```